# Array Index out of range exception C#

Tags: c#, arrays, average

I'm trying to find the closest number in an array when compared to the array's average. The array will be determined in the main program. Here's the current code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    double[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 5 };    
    double m1 = Miidi(numbers);         
    double m2 = Miidi(new double[] { 1 });  
    double m3 = Miidi(new double[] { 3, 3 });
    double m4 = Miidi(new double[] { });
    Console.WriteLine(m1);
    Console.WriteLine(m2);
    Console.WriteLine(m3);
    Console.WriteLine(m4);
}

public static double Miidi(double[] numbers)
{
    double average = 0;
    average = numbers.Average();

    double nearest = FindNearest(numbers, average);
    return nearest;
}

public static double FindNearest(double[] t, double avg)
{
    double searchValue = avg;
    double currentNearest = t[0];
    double currentDiff = currentNearest - searchValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    {
        double diff = t[i] - avg;
        if (diff < currentDiff)
        {
            currentDiff = diff;
            currentNearest = t[i];
        }
    }
    return currentNearest;
}
```

}

I'm getting an array index out of range exception. I tried the methods you guys provided and changed the <= to < in the loop, but I'm still getting the exception. I provided the main program for clarification.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in using the debugger? Index out of range is very different to null reference exception.

Comment: The IndexOutOfRangeException happens because you loop `t` using `<=`. Your int `i` will be +1 more than `t.Length`. Remove the = to get rid of the exception.

Comment: You also need to say `Math.Abs(t[i] - avg)`, or your method will produce wrong results. And you can start the loop at 1 instead of 0. And you can just say `numbers.Average()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to my comment:

An array/collection starts always at 0.

e.g.

```
t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 2;
t[2] = 3;
t[3] = 4;
```

If you loop `t` like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= t.Length; i++)
```

then `i` will count the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

because `t.Length = 4` and you say `i less than equal 4`.

But since an array starts at 0, `i` may not be greater than 3, otherwise it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeExcepiton`.

If you change your loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
```

it will finish without any exception, because `i` wont be greater than 3 now.

**UPDATE:**

Additional to your comments:

You pass an empty array to your method `Miidi()`. Just check if there are any items in the array:

```
public static double Miidi(double[] numbers)
{
    if (numbers != null && numbers.Length > 0)
    {
        double average = 0;
        average = numbers.Average();

        double nearest = FindNearest(numbers, average);
        return nearest;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out once I get home.

Comment: Aight, tried it with no luck. I added the main program in my post for clarification.

Comment: Is there another error or what's not working as expected now?

Comment: Still a index out of range exception at "double currentNearest = t[0];"

Comment: If you debug it, on which loop is the exception caused? m1, m2, m3 or m4?

Comment: Note that line: `double m4 = Miidi(new double[] { });`. This is an array with no items.

Comment: m4. That is probably the culprit. The thing is that I can't change the main program as it is provided for me and I just have to write the subroutines. Should I add an empty array check there?

Comment: That did the trick, man. Thanks a ton! I also added the Math.Abs method to get precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= t.Length; i++)
```

as

```
for (int i = 0; i <= t.Length - 1; i++)
```

because an Array starts at 0

Comment: Or simply `i < t.Length`

Comment: You just had to say it :P